Expected value of $\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n}}$
So consider method of moments based on the second moment applied to Poisson distribution with parameter $\theta$. We get $\hat{\theta} = \sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n} + \frac{1}{4}} - \frac{1}{2}$. Next, I'd like to compute MSE,which boils up to  $E\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2}{n}} = E ((\bar{X^2})^{\frac{1}{2}})$ estimation. This is where I stuck because I do not know how to use Taylor here or what else could I use since probability function for $\bar{X^2}$ is really hard to compute. Originally, I'd like to compare it with MSE of first order estimator, which is $\hat{\theta}_1 = \bar{X}$ with MSE of $\frac{\theta}{n}$

This is somewhat unclear, can you edit? What do you mean by generating function $x^2$ ?

it means we take function $g(x) = x^2$, compute $f(\theta) = Eg(X) = \theta + \theta^2$, find the inverse $f^{-1}$ and consider $f^{-1}(\frac{\sum g(X_i)}{n})$ as our estimator. Just the regular method of moments

Thanks to @leonbloy, I can now complete the answer.
Let's estimate $MSE(\hat{\theta}) = E((\hat{\theta} - \theta)^2)=D(\hat{\theta}) + E^2(\hat{\theta} - \theta)$, where  $Z = \hat\theta=\sqrt{\bar{X^2}+\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}$.
$D(\hat{\theta}) = D(\hat{\theta} + \frac{1}{2}) = E(\bar{X^2}+\frac{1}{4})-E^2(\sqrt{\bar{X^2}+\frac{1}{4}})=(\theta+\frac{1}{2})^2-(\frac{1}{2}+\mu_Z)^2=(\theta-\mu_Z)(\theta+\mu_Z+1)$
$E^2(\hat{\theta} - \theta) = (\mu_Z -\theta)^2$
To sum up, $MSE(\hat{\theta})=(\theta-\mu_Z)(\theta+\mu_Z+1+\theta-\mu_Z)=(\theta-\mu_Z)(2\theta+1) \approx \frac{2\theta+1}{2n}$, where the last step was approximation of $\mu_Z$ which @leonbloy deduced

Let $W = \frac1N \sum X_i^2 + \frac14$. Then we have $\mu_W= \lambda  + \lambda ^2 + 
\frac 14 = (\lambda +\frac12)^2$ and $\sigma_W^2=\frac1N (4 \lambda ^3 + 6 \lambda ^2 + \lambda )$
Now, if $Z = \sqrt{W} - \frac12 $, we can approximate
$$\mu_Z \approx \sqrt{ \mu_W} - \frac12 \frac{1}{4\, \mu_W^{3/2}} \sigma_W^2 - \frac 12 = 
\lambda  - \frac1N \frac{\lambda \, \left( 4 {{\lambda }^{2}}+ 6 \lambda  +1\right) }{{{\left( 2 \lambda  +1\right) }^{3}}} $$
We can deduce that the estimator is biased (but asymptotically unbiased).
In particular, for $\lambda \gg 1$
$$\mu_Z \approx   \lambda - \frac {1}{2N}$$

I think the case where $\lambda$ is small could be more interesting, as empirically when $\lambda < \frac 1n$ you seem to get a smaller expected mean square error using $\hat \lambda_2 = Z$ than with $\hat \lambda_1 = \bar X$.

that i agree with, thanks, but my question was about MSE estimation $E((Z - \theta)^2)$, maybe you can expand you answer to complete it?
